# Jaxb generated class used JAXBElement instead of specified type

Tags: java, code-generation, jaxb

This question has been asked in various guises - but I feel there is still room to catalogue this further.

I have an xsd with two element definitions

```
<xs:complexType name="elementA">
   <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="date" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="lastXdigits" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
   </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

This generates:

```
protected String date;
@XmlElementRef(name = "lastXdigits", namespace = "http://xxxxxxx", type = JAXBElement.class)
protected JAXBElement<String> lastXDigits;
```

Changing the xsd to:

```
<xs:element name="lastXdigits" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="1"/>
```

results in:

```
protected String date;
@XmlElement(name = "lastXdigits", required = true, nillable = true)
protected String lastXDigits;
```

and using:

```
<xs:element name="lastXdigits" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
```

results in:

```
protected String date;
@XmlElement(name = "lastXdigits")
protected String lastXDigits;
```

This seems extremely odd to me. Why is lastXDigits generated as a JAXBElement type in the first case and why does a String type not suffice in all cases? Also, why should jaxb treat these two elements differently when their definition apart from name are identical?

I'm using a jaxb-xjc ant task from jaxb 2.0.5.

Does this look suspicious or is there good justification for these differences?

Answer (score 9):

If `nillable="true"` together with `minOccurs="0"` it is impossible to represent the values with just a `String`. What would `null` mean? Does it mean that it was null, or that it occurred 0 times? But I guess that is somewhat moot when it comes to just a String.

Compare with empty list. A null list is certainly different to an empty one.

Comment: i guess this is relevant if you are interested in the distinction between no element being present and the value of the element being null, but I guess in most cases no-one really cares and the extra level of indirection is just a nuisance.

Comment: Yes, but I guess in some instances it may be a valid distinction to make.